# Control two google charts at once with one control filter - possible?

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to add two types of charts into one dashboard and filter them by country, like so:

the initial values shown should be for Europe, done via

```
'state': {'selectedValues': ['Europe']}
```

Chart 1 is a pie chart and should show the split between two variables within Europe and each country for let's say 2012, like so:

```
['Country',  'Speciality', 'Amount'],
['Europe', 'XYZ', 20441],
['Europe', 'ABC', 5355],
['Austria', 'XYZ', 477],
['Austria', 'ABC', 153],         
['BeNeLux', 'XYZ', 1512],
['BeNeLux', 'ABC', 298],
['France', 'XYZ', 3080],
['France', 'ABC', 792],
```

and so on

Chart 2 should refer to the same two variables, but adding quarters, i.e. Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4. Ideally I would like to have this as a 100% stacked column chart. Columns being Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4.

Question is: How do I add both charts into the dashboard and have the control filter both charts if I select for example France?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Binding the filter to two charts is easy, as [the documentation says](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#establish_dependencies):

> ```
>   // One-to-many binding where 'ageSelector' drives two charts.
>   dashboard.bind(agePicker, [ageVsSalaryScatterPlot, ageBarChart]);
> ```

This will mean that if you select 'Europe' it will change the filter for both charts. From your question it seems you may be a bit unclear on how to actually set this up (since your data isn't formatted correctly).

You will need 5 things:

1. [`DataTable`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) containing information for all charts (so if you want quarter information, it needs to be in the `DataTable` as well
2. [`Dashboard`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#dashboardobject) object to contain the charts and controls
3. [`ChartWrapper`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject) object for the pie chart.
4. `ChartWrapper` object for the stacked column chart
5. [`ControlWrapper`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#controlwrapperobject) object for the selector

## DataTable

Currently you have your data with only 3 columns:

```
['Country',  'Speciality', 'Amount'],
['Europe', 'XYZ', 20441],
['Europe', 'ABC', 5355],
['Austria', 'XYZ', 477],
['Austria', 'ABC', 153],         
['BeNeLux', 'XYZ', 1512],
['BeNeLux', 'ABC', 298],
['France', 'XYZ', 3080],
['France', 'ABC', 792],
```

Since you also want quarters, you need to add that information as well.

```
['Country',  'Speciality', 'Amount', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'],
['Europe', 'XYZ', 20441, 1, 2, 3, 4],
['Europe', 'ABC', 5355, 1, 2, 3, 4],
['Austria', 'XYZ', 477, 1, 2, 3, 4],
['Austria', 'ABC', 153, 1, 2, 3, 4],         
['BeNeLux', 'XYZ', 1512, 1, 2, 3, 4],
['BeNeLux', 'ABC', 298, 1, 2, 3, 4],
['France', 'XYZ', 3080, 1, 2, 3, 4],
['France', 'ABC', 792, 1, 2, 3, 4],
```

## Dashboard Object

A dashboard object points to a `<div>` element that contains the other `<div>` elements for the charts and controls. So in your case, something like:

Then you create the dashboard using code like this:

```
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
```

## ChartWrappers

So you have two charts, and you need to create two separate wrappers. A wrapper basically gives all the details on what that chart will need to be created:

- Where on the page it goes (the `<div>`)
- Where it will take its data from
- What type of chart / options it will use

The piechart only uses columns 0, 1, 2, so you set the 'view' property of the object to limit the data to those columns.

Do the same with the stackedcolumnchart, using columns 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Both charts need to take data from the same `DataTable` though, otherwise filtering one chart won't affect the other (the filter will apply to the DataTable, so if you have two of them, you can only change one at a time).

## ControlWrapper

Like the ChartWrapper, you need to create a ControlWrapper object that has all the details about the Control you use.

Once you have all your objects set up, you can draw the dashboard and bind the control to the two charts with the code at the top of this answer.

## References

If you're still confused, play around with [Google Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#full_dashboard) for Dashboards to get an idea of how it works.